# Compare all elements in two numpy arrays without using a loop

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a matrix and a vector of the centroids of each row in the matrix. I would like to compare every element in the matrix to every element in the vector and find which element in the vector of centroids is closest to the data point in the matrix. Is there a way to do this without using a loop? I will use a large amount of a data and want it to be as fast as possible

Here is a very simple example in python of the way in which I am doing it right now:

```
import scipy as sp
test_array = sp.array([(1,1,1),(3,4,5),(6,12,18)])
sumx = test_array.sum(axis=1)
centroid_vector = sumx / len(test[0])
for i in centroid_vector:
    x = abs(test_array - i)
    minimum = sp.argmin(x)
```

The desired result is a matrix with the minimum distance, original value (from test_array) and the index of the element in the centroid vector to which the distance is the smallest. In this case, it would look something like this:

```
[(0, 1, 1), 
 (0, 1, 1), 
 (0, 1, 1),
 (1, 3, 2), 
 (0, 4, 2),
 ...
 (6, 18, 3)]
```

Comment: Is `test` a Numpy ndarray?

Comment: do you expect one min value (between all matrix' values and all vector' values) or a three min values (one min for each i of `centroid_vector`)?

Comment: Please post the desired result for your example.

Comment: `np.unravel_index(np.argmin(np.abs(np.subtract.outer(test.mean(axis=1), test.ravel())), axis=1), test.shape)` gives for each component of the centroid the coordinates of the closest value in `test`. Output: `(array([0, 1, 2]), array([0, 1, 1]))`. These are the top left, the center and the bottom center,

Comment: @wwii, yes it is a numpy array, scipy is imported

Comment: @Ben.T for each data point in the matrix, which centroid it is closest to

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution to your question:

```
import scipy as sp
test_array = sp.array([(1,1,1),(3,4,5),(6,12,18)])
# Create the centroid another way but yours is fine
centroid_vector = test_array.sum(axis=1)/test_array.shape[1]
# Generate an array with all the difference between 
# each element of test_array (row) and centroid_vector (column)
delta_array = abs(test_array.reshape((9,1)) - centroid_vector)
# Finally, the first column of your output is delta_array.min(axis=1), 
# the second is test_array.reshape((9,1))
# and the third is delta_array.argmin(axis=1)
# so you can do:
array_output = sp.array([delta_array.min(axis=1),test_array.reshape((9)),
                         delta_array.argmin(axis=1)]).transpose()
```

Note: that the index of element in `centroid_vector` start at 0 (python convention) and not 1 as in your question, but just do `delta_array.argmin(axis=1) +1` if you want 1, 2, or 3 in your third column.

Note 2: avoid using `sum` as the name of a variable, it's a built-in function and it might bring some trouble after in your code.